# convert an object with enum propertie to Map<String,Object>

Tags: java, enums, jackson

I have a enum definition like:

```
public enum Color {
    RED,
    BLUE,
    YELLOW;
}
```

And a class when the enum is referenced:

```
public class Car{
    ...

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Color color;

    ...
}
```

When I convert this to a `Map` like:

```
Map<String, Object> toMap = MAPPER.convertValue(t, Map.class);
```

Then the type of the value with the key "color" is `String` not `Color`.

Comment: What is `t`? [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What are you trying to do? By annotating a field with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` you're declaring that its value should be converted from  a String in the database to `Color` enum value. But then, in your `Map` you declare the key as `String`. Obviously you want a map which key is `Color`, not `String`. Also, what is the value type on this map? Why is `Object`? Please don't tell me you are putting `Car` objects as as values in the map.

Comment: Generics can be used.

Comment: It would not be there most probably erasure will erase the type information at runtime. Try casting the same back to Color and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Could you try by using Color rather than String in Map.

Map<Color, Object> tAsMap = MAPPER.convertValue(t, Map.class);

Comment: i need the key is String :v, the value of key "color" is string not Color

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `MAPPER` is a default `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` without any customizations.

And your question is, how to convert a `Car` object to a `Map`. And in the converted map, the value of `color` key should be an `Enum`, instead of `String`?

If that is your question, then I'll give you some of my thoughts on this.

`ObjectMapper.convertValue` is a method for doing two-step conversion, first it  serializes your `Car` into JSON (your `color` field is `String` now), then it deserializes the JSON to `Map` in order to finish the conversion. After the deserialization step, `color` field is now `String` in the new map.

You may have to manually convert the value of `color` key from `String` to `Enum` again. Or you will eventually have to find a way to customize/override the "JSON to Map" default deserialization behavior. 
You can read more about how to create a custom deserialization here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization.